# How do I clear chrome.storage.sync for testing my extension?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I am making a little logic game as a chrome extension, to add a high score I wanted to use chrome.storage.sync. I want to only create a variable if it doesn't exist (the first time someone is opening the extension). To test if what I wrote works I have to clear all data for myself, how could I do that? (the documentation speaks senior developer and I am not one of those so I don't understand)

https://developer.chrome.com/docs/extensions/reference/storage/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
chrome.storage.local.clear()
```

thats will Removes all items from storage.

you can also remove some keys and not all items by,

```js
chrome.storage.local.get((data) => {
  // here you get all data and you can decide which keys to delete, 
  // in this case im deleting all keys explicitly

  chrome.storage.local.remove(Object.keys(data), resolve)
})
```

Comment: Do I just run it in my script.js file and then get rid of it later?

Comment: you can do it in your background page while developing

Comment: chrome.storage.sync.clear(). He is not using local?